# Python HSAudioTag for WMA files always returns 0?

Tags: python

I'm using the Python library HSAudioTag, and I'm trying to read the track number in my files, however, without fail, the file returns 0 as the track number, even if it's much higher. Does anybody have any idea how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: The solution was to go into the code, and change the following lines to:
_Line 118:_ **self.track = u''**
_Lines 149-152:_ **self.track = int(self._fields.get(TRACK, u'')) + 1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to go into the code, and change the following lines to: *Line 118:* **self.track = u''** *Lines 149-152:* **self.track = int(self._fields.get(TRACK, u'')) + 1**